# jquery slider is not draggable in IE9

Tags: jquery, uislider

I am using the following jquery slider

http://filamentgroup.com/examples/slider_v2/index3.php

In IE9,When I try to drag it,I am not able to drag it.I dont know how to make it work in IE9 where as its working in IE8 and other browsers fine,Please anyone suggest me how to solve the issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Care to post a sample bit of your code, so we can see what you're doing? Could be a syntax error. JsFiddle is useful, too.

Comment: There is no change in the code Tieson,you can check the the url,as the slider is not working in IE9.I use the same code what they used in the slider.I dont know how to make it draggable.

Comment: Not sure if you fixed this yet, as bygrace said below, your jquery ui library is old, I had a similar issue.  Infact 1.8.2 failed too, 1.8.23 is now out and works a treat in IE9 though

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on jQuery 1.7.2 and jQuery UI 1.8.1. What fixed it for me was upgrading to jQuery UI 1.8.2. Hope that helps.